# WCF windows authentication security error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

i have some code that tries impersonate the callers windows security settings and then connect to another WCF service on a different machine

```
WindowsIdentity callerWindowsIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
using (callerWindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://serverName:9990/TestService1"));
    ChannelFactory<WCFTest.ConsoleHost.IService1> channel = new ChannelFactory<WCFTest.ConsoleHost.IService1>(binding, endpoint);
    WCFTest.ConsoleHost.IService1 service = channel.CreateChannel();
    return service.PrintMessage(msg);
}
```

But I get the error:
"the caller was not authenticated by the service"
System.ServiceModel .... The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed ...

The credentials I am trying to impersonate are valide windows credential for the box the service is on.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

In order to support your scenario, you need to have an understanding of how [Protocol Transition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx) and [Constrained Delegation](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=What%20is%20constrained%20delegation%3F) work. You will need to configure both Active Directory and your WCF service endpoint(s) to support this. Note the use of the Service Principal Name (SPN). Take a look at the following link and see if they help you. The article has a sample to demonstrate the complete end-to-end configuration required to make this work.

[How To: Impersonate the Original Caller in WCF Calling from a Web Application](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=How%20To%20-%20Impersonate%20the%20Original%20Caller%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Web%20Application)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with marc_s this is the double-hop problem.

You need to get the windows authentication all the way through, therefore:

- The request must be made in the context of a windows users
- IIS must be configured to use windows authentication
- Web.config must be set up for windows authentication with impersonate = true
- The user that your application pool is running as, must be allowed to impersonate a user. This is the usual place where the double-hop problem occurs.

There is a right called "Impersonate a client after authentication"

http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/10/16/wmi-troubleshooting-impersonation-rights.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation from you service to the next is a tricky issue, known as "double-hop" issue.

I don't have a final answer for that (I typically avoid it by using an explicit service account for the service that needs to call another service).

BUT: you should definitely check out the [WCF Security Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity/) on CodePlex and search for "Impersonation" - there are quite a few articles there that explain all the ins and outs of impersonating an original caller and why it's tricky.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have the credentials right on both hops, the next thing that *could* be causing the issue is the lack of the EndpointDnsIdentity being set on the endpoint.

```
DnsEndpointIdentity identity = new DnsEndpointIdentity("localhost"); // localhost is default. Change if your service uses a different value in the service's config.
Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://serverName:9990/TestService1");
endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri, identity, new AddressHeaderCollection());
```